# (Angular) Should I have my http services in core folder (as singleton) or in lazy loaded modules itself?

Tags: angular, http, lazy-loading, ng-modules

(Angular) Should I have my http services in core folder (as singleton) or in lazy loaded modules itself?

Which approach is better?

Comment: Your question is a bit too subjective for StackOverflow. You might do better asking in the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new `providedIn` property of the `Injectable decorator` (since Angular v6). There is no need to register services in modules **AT ALL**.